# Does this game approach a zero chance of winning as the game gets longer?

Tags: probability

There is a series of tiles, either solid or not (50 50 chance). I consider it a success if you can make it to the last tile. There is L tiles. You start on the first tile. If you ‘run’ along n solid tiles, you can make it across a chasm n tiles wide or less. If you were running across A tiles and jumped across B tiles, it would still be as if you had run across A-B tiles. As L approach’s infinity, does the chance you can succeed on a random series of tiles approach 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If at any point you have encountered more blank tiles than solid tiles, then you have lost, regardless of the order of the tiles. You can model the difference between the number of blank and solid tiles as a 1-dimensional random walk. An infinite 1D random walk will cross every value an infinite number of times - one of those values will be 0, where there are an equal number of blank and solid tiles. You will cross that point almost surely (with probability 1) as the walk length increases to infinity, meaning that at some point, you will have encountered more blank tiles than solid ones.

As the length of the run increases to infinity, the probability of success approaches 0.